# Mysql query based on row value of another table

Tags: mysql

Have two mysql tables such as

**Table1**

```
Id
Field1
Field2
```

**Table2**

```
Id
LinkId
Field3
Field4
```

The common fields to link the tables are `Table1.Id` and `Table2.LinkId.`

Also important tha Table2 can have multiple rows where LinkId are the same.

So what I have been trying to figure is a mysql query to Select all rows in Table1 that have a linked row or more in Table2 where Field3 contains a certain value. Is this easily possible?

Comment: Hint  ...  JOIN  ..   anyway update you question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `JOIN`

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1 A JOIN Table2 B ON A.Id = B.LinkID
WHERE B.Field3 IN ('Your inputs')
```

Comment: Wouldn't this query return multiple rows if `Table2` has more than one rows matching the criteria?

Comment: No.. it will return all the rowa of table1 with matching with table2 linkedid

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar A, it will definitely return multiple rows if table2 has more than one matching row per id of table1. You should try `distinct` or `group by` to make it unique if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple tables in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table2.Field3 = 'certain value'
AND Table1.Id = Table2.LinkId
```